# Conversion images pdf to text

Tags: pdf, ocr, calibre

I have a 500page pdf scan of a 15th century book.

I wish to convert it into a single txt file of any format so as to be able to work on it and/or export it to epub.

Calibre is unable to process it.
I tried to tesseract it, but it just does not work. 
Splitting pages one by one manually is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by splitting pages one by one? Splitting pages would be a 'sudo apt-get install pdftk' and then 'pdftk filename.pdf burst'. Then you could pipe it into tesseract (if the problem was that tesseract takes only single page input).

Comment: pdftk seems to be an excellent first step to get tesseract working :) I'm giving this a try now.

Comment: I have no experience with tesseract. But should it not take pdf as input, you might also need imagemagick to convert the pdf into a fileformat that is accepted.